# Variable is being reused even though its variable scope does not mention reuse=True

Tags: python, tensorflow

In [Sharing Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope#understanding_tfget_variable) tutorial, it says how to use the function `get_variable()` to reuse previously created variables.

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo"):      # Creation
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])

with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):    # Re-using
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
```

But in the implementation of `_linear()` function in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py#L982), `get_variable()` function is used as follows.

```
with vs.variable_scope(scope) as outer_scope:
    weights = vs.get_variable(
        _WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME, [total_arg_size, output_size],
        dtype=dtype,
        initializer=kernel_initializer)
```

As I know `_linear()` function is used to do the operation `args * W + bias`. Here weights(W) must be reusable.
 
But in the way that they are using `get_variable()` function inside `_linear()` function, I think a new variable is created everytime. But `W` has to be reusable for Neural Network to work.

I'm seeking to understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

They use the following fact documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope):

> Note that the reuse flag is inherited: if we open a reusing scope, then all its sub-scopes become reusing as well.

So if your scope is embedded into a parent scope that sets the reuse flag accordingly, you are all set. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def get_v():
  with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
      v = tf.get_variable("v", shape=(), initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
  return v

with tf.variable_scope("bar"):
  v = get_v()
with tf.variable_scope("bar", reuse=True):
  v1 = get_v()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(v)
sess.run(v1) # returns the same value
```

In the present case, the parent scope is created by the parent class `tf.python.layers.Layer`.